AuthO Tenants for Application
I am new to the security realm and advanced authorization and authentication subjects like OAuth and OpenID connect.
I am trying to secure a simple application with has an Angular front end and Springboot REST backend. I can only find literature on how to create an Auth0 tenant for either a single page app by itself or one that runs entirely in Springboot.
what types of tenants to create for such an application and how tokens will work with such an application?
